# Formidable Forms - send an email when a form entry has been updated

Tags: php, wordpress, formidable

I have a Formidable Form which is editable to logged in users on my website.

When the form has been edited I wish to send an email to a pre-set email.

```
function send_entry_update_email($entry_id, $form_id) {
  // Get the entry details
  $entry = FrmEntry::getOne($entry_id);
  $form = FrmForm::getOne($form_id);

  // Get the email recipient
  $recipient = 'email@xyz.com';

  // Compose the email subject and message
  $subject = 'Formidable Form Entry Updated: ' . $form->name;
  $message = 'The Formidable Forms entry with ID ' . $entry_id . ' has been updated.' . "\n";
  $message .= 'Form: ' . $form->name . "\n";
  $message .= 'Entry ID: ' . $entry_id . "\n";

  // Send the email
  wp_mail($recipient, $subject, $message);
}
add_action('frm_after_update_entry', 'send_entry_update_email', 10, 2);
```

There is no error in the log. The plugin has a setting for sending an update email when an entry is updated but this only works when it is edited from the WordPress admin end and not the front end.

Emails are sending for everything else on my website.